# Looking for a convenient way to add time space

Tags: python, datetime

I want to add a month datetime to my current datetime, if I do this, I only can convert the datetime to timestamp, then add the timestamp space:

If is the February, I will add `28 * 24 * 3600`.
If is a solar month of 31 days I will add `31 * 24 * 3600`.
If is a solar month of 30 days I will add `30 * 24 * 3600`.

Then convert to datetime again.

So, there is a lot of things to do, python is comfortable for developer, if there is a simpler and more convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


def add_month(date):
    days_in_month = monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]
    new_date = date + timedelta(days=days_in_month)
    return new_date


print(add_month(datetime(2017, 1, 1)))
> 2017-02-01 00:00:00

print(add_month(datetime(2017, 2, 5)))
> 2017-03-05 00:00:00
```

---

Or with a third party library [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io):

```
from datetime import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def add_month(date):
    new_date = date + relativedelta(months=1)
    return new_date


print(add_month(datetime(2017, 1, 1)))
> 2017-02-01 00:00:00

print(add_month(datetime(2017, 2, 5)))
> 2017-03-05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [relativedelta](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/relativedelta.html) :

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def addTimeSpace(ori_datetime, relative_date):

    day = relativedelta(days=+1)

    added_datetime = ori_datetime + relative_date
    if ori_datetime.day > added_datetime.day:
        added_datetime = added_datetime + day

    return added_datetime

print(addTimeSpace(datetime.now(), relativedelta(years=+4, months=+1)))  #there will output: 2021-10-26 20:00:53.222794
```